# setprecision() function in C++

Tags: c++

How to store the returned value of setprecision() ?

For example:-

float fl = /* assign the value returned by setprecision() */ ;

Comment: I think you are mistaking here something. What are you trying to achieve with setprecision? I think you want to round up or down your float value?

Comment: The return type of `std::setprecision` is unspecified.  You are only supposed to use it as a stream operator, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: Are you talking about [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) ? If so, the return value should not be used in other way than pushing it to an stream through the `<<` or `>>` operators.

Comment: It seems you have some major misunderstandings about input in C++. Please [get some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read and learn properly.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision ?

Comment: you could try `auto& x = setprecision(n);` but even this may fail  and definitely it wont do what you expect. What is your actualy aim? Why do you want to store the returned value?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up `setprecision()`. Let's clear it with an example shall we?

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

See the `double f`? Okay so `f` has a value of `3.14159`. And if we want to control how much places we need to show after the decimal place we'll use `setprecision()`.

> Sets the decimal precision to be used to format floating-point values
> on output operations.
>
> Behaves as if member precision were called with n as argument on the
> stream on which it is inserted/extracted as a manipulator (it can be
> inserted/extracted on input streams or output streams).
>
> This manipulator is declared in header .

and why do you need to use `setprecision()` for assigning value to a variable?

Hopefully this will give you a clear idea of how to use `setprecision()`

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double var = 10.0 / 3.0 ;
    cout << setprecision(10) << var;

    return 0;
}
```

**result:** `3.333333333`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are accepting an input float and you set the precision of the input

```cpp
std::string s;
std::cin >> std::setprecision(3) >> s;
float f = std::stof(s);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

You could also do something similar with other streams